# insuring my car under girlfriends policy

Tags: united-states, car-insurance

I live in Indiana in an apartment with my girlfriend, just bought a car with her as a cosigner but her name is not on registration. Can she insure the car under her policy with me as a driver.

Comment: So whose name _is_ on the registration and whose name is on the title? Automobile insurance policies _generally_ are issued to the _owner_ of the car or possibly the leaseholder. If the car has been purchased with a loan, the insurance policy will record the lender as having a lien on the car, etc., so whose name is on the loan, if any?

Comment: Normally insurance companies require any driver in the household to be listed on the policy if they are going to drive the car at all.